# Transistor part number selection software

Tags: transistors, mosfet, software, bjt, fet

I know there are online/offline softwares for finding equivalents or known transistor datasheets but is there any software that works inversely? For example that I can ask the software for a transistor with VCEmax  or cutoff frequency equal to some value and the software gives part number suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one - [from Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/transistors-bipolar-bjt-single).

They aren't a disinterested party - they want to sell transistors - and its quality is only as good as the data entry clerks make it - but it will allow selection on min/max values for a variety of parameters including your suggestions.

It is rather slow, but I find it moderately useful.

And they have similar selectors for a variety of other components, including passives.

I would expect most distributors have similar selectors : perhaps there are others which work better? This is just the one I use most.

Comment: +1 for good suggestion.Yes, many companies or even resellers have such facilities "TO SELL THEIR PRODUCTS" as you mentioned also ( for example Fairchild has somthing like that) but I am looking for a specific software that covers more than one company

Comment: This covers all manufacturers that Farnell distribute. Which is ... probably most big names. In any case, most discrete transistors are multi-sourced (different makers sell very similar parts under the same name) so it covers most bases well. If you have extreme requirements (Vcemax > 1000V or something) you need to cultivate relationships with the manufacturers who specialise in that area : no general tool will help. Even then, this selector (or similar) will point you at the major players.